# Omitting Duplicates

Tags: java, string, compare

So I need to make a program that functions as a mastermind game with a string of numbers. This particular method tells the guesser how many numbers, that they user guessed, are in the actual secret number. I have the code to pass a test involving a guess with only 5 unique numbers, but I cant determine how to count a guess with more than one of a number. For example, the secret number being 12345 and the guess being 11111 the method should return 1, however it's returning 5. Any suggestions? This is what I have so far:

```
public int uniqueDigitsFound(String secretNumber, String guess) {

      int counter = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while(i<=secretNumber.length()-1){
          if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(0)){  
              counter++;
          }
          if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(1)){
              counter++;
          }
          if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(2)){
              counter++;
          }
          if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(3)){
              counter++;
          }
          if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(4)){
              counter++;
          }
          i++;
          }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Your while loop should use guess, not secretNumber, since you're checking against character in secretNumber within the while loop; and, since secretNumber.charAt(0) is always 1 each time through your loop counter will be incremented - thus you get 5, instead of 1. So, there are several programming errors in your function.

Answer (score 0):

In the game MasterMind, the goal is to correctly guess a secret sequence, matching not just values but also position in the sequence. The test case for MasterMind looks like this:

```
SECRET  GUESS    ANSWER
12345   11111      1
12345   12222      2
12345   12223      2
12345   12345      5
12345   123        3
12345   12345123   5
```

To solve this, validate that each character in the guess matches the value character in the same position in the secret:

```
int correctCharacters(String secret, String guess) {

    int correct = 0;

    // Make sure the size of the guess does not under or overflow the secret.
    for(int i = 0; i < guess.length() && i < secret.length(); i++) {

        // If guess and secret match in a position, count as correct.
        if(guess.charAt(i) == secret.charAt(i)) {
            correct++;
        }
    }

    return correct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int uniqueDigitsFound(String secretNumber, String guess)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < secretNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            if (guess.charAt(i) == secretNumber.charAt(i))
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

This one if numbers are actually unique and no identical numbers are allowed... you just have to check if number you found was found before.

```
public static int uniqueDigitsFound(String secretNumber, String guess)
{
    int[] numbersGuessed = new int[5];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < secretNumber.Length; x++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < secretNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            if (secretNumber.charAt(x) == guess.charAt(x)){
                bool uniqueFind = true;
                for(int y=0; y<numbersGuessed.Length;y++)
                   if(numbersGuessed.charAt(y)=secretNumber.charAt(x))
                      uniqueFind = false;
                if(unique){
                    numbersGuessed[counter] == secretNumber.charAt(x)
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. One simple way is just to keep a Set of numbers that have already been encountered, e.g.

```
public int uniqueDigitsFound(String secretNumber, String guess) {

  int counter = 0;
  int i = 0;
  Set<Character> charactersThatHaveAlreadyBeenProcessed = new HashSet<>();

  while(i<=secretNumber.length()-1){
      if (!charactersThatHaveAlreadyBeenProcessed.contains(guess.charAt(i)) {
        if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(0)){  
            counter++;
        }

        if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(1)){
            counter++;
        }

        if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(2)){
            counter++;
        }

        if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(3)){
            counter++;
        }

        if(guess.charAt(i)==secretNumber.charAt(4)){
            counter++;
        }

        charactersThatHaveAlreadyBeenProcessed.add(guess.charAt(i));
      }

      i++;
  }

  return counter;
}
```

Comment: btw you could write this a little better as well: you could loop through the secretNumber's characters instead of having 5 repeated if statements.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jan Nielsen's . Your method that checks for uniqueness of each guessed digit  can be defined with something like the below  , It takes every guess and append it to an array  of already existing ones , sort the array and then do the comparison  "Or use an Arraylist".

Some method:

```
int[] str={1 , 2 , .......};
Arrays.sort(str);
for (int i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == str[i - 1]) {
    System.out.println("Dupe: " + str[i];
  }
}
```